# Convert panda dataframe to h5 file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, h5py

I want to store my dataframe in h5 file. My dataframe is:

```
dfbhbh=pd.DataFrame([m1bhbh,m2bhbh,adcobhbh,edcobhbh,alisabhbh,elisabhbh,tevolbhbh,distbhbh,metalbhbh,compbhbh,weightbhbh]).T
dfbhbh.columns=['m_1','m_2','a_DCO','e_DCO','a_LISA','e_LISA','t_evol','dist','Z','component','weight']
```

I am trying to convert it using:

```
hf=h5py.File('anew', 'w')
for i in range(len(dfbhbh)):
    hf.create_dataset('simulations',list(dfbhbh.iloc[i]))
```

And I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: Can't convert element 9 (low_alpha_disc) to hsize_t
```

I removed the entire array of the component (even though it is extremely significant) but the code did not run.

I also tried to insert directly the data in the h5 file like this

```
hf.create_dataset('simulations', m1bhbh)
```

I got this error

```
Dimensionality is too large (dimensionality is too large)
```

The variable 'm1bhbh' is a float type with length 1499.

Comment: Welcom to SO! Please provide a sample of you df.  you can do this: Post the result of the following ```dfbhbh.head(10).to_dict()```.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
hf.create_dataset('simulations', data = m1bhbh)
```

instead of

```
hf.create_dataset('simulations', m1bhbh)
```

(Don't forget to clear outputs before running it.)